# Como agrupar un campo por los 3 últimos registros?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, mysql-workbench

Buenas, tengo esta tabla a continuación:
[image: tabla tb__armario]
Lo que necesito es agruparlos por los últimos 3 registros para el campo "messurement_date" es decir que me quedaría de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siendo:

a_kw(1) = Ultimo Registro 
a_kw(2) = Penultimo Registro 
a_kw(3) = Antepenultimo Registro

total_kw(1) = Ultimo Registro
total_kw(2) = Penultimo Registro

Caso contrario si no tuviera registros, que se muestre 0.

Espero por favor me pudieran ayudar...

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente query agrupa los últimos tres registros de tu tabla `tb_armario`

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM tb_armario 
ORDER BY messurement_date DESC
```

.

Comment: Eso serviría para SQL, no para Mysql :/! no me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Esta consulta te obtiene los últimos 3 registros de tu tabla `tb_temario`

```
select * from tb_armario ORDER BY messurement_date DESC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el resultado que buscas, debes construirlo a partir de tablas más pequeñas. Fíjate que el último paso consiste en un JOIN de tres subconsultas intermedias en las que se combinan los resultados obtenidos para el último, penúltimo y antepenúltimo registro (el último se obtiene con un MAX y, para los demás, ya tienes que hacer una resta que elimine los últimos y sucesivos). Puedes extraer de la consulta final el código de las consultas intermedias para ver qué resultados se van obteniendo, las tabulaciones te ayudarán a identificar cada parte. Es laborioso, pero no es complicado. Para verlo un poco más claro, te puedo enviar el álgebra relacional explicando cada paso. Al final de la consulta tienes el código para reproducir la tabla con sus datos e ir haciendo las pruebas que necesites.

```
SELECT idclient,IFNULL(a_kw3,0) a_kw3,IFNULL(b_kw3,0) b_kw3,
  a_kw2,b_kw2,total_kw2,a_kw1,b_kw1,total_kw1
  FROM (
    SELECT idclient,A_KW a_kw1,B_KW b_kw1,total_KW total_kw1 FROM (
        SELECT idclient,MAX(messurement_date) messurement_date
          FROM tb__armario GROUP BY 1  
      ) c1 JOIN tb__armario USING(idclient,messurement_date) 
  ) kw1 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT idclient,A_KW a_kw2,B_KW b_kw2,total_KW total_kw2 FROM (
        SELECT idclient,MAX(messurement_date) messurement_date
          FROM (
            SELECT * FROM tb__armario LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT idclient,MAX(messurement_date) messurement_date
                  FROM tb__armario GROUP BY 1 
              ) c1 USING(idclient,messurement_date)
              WHERE c1.idclient IS NULL  
          ) tb__armario GROUP BY 1
      ) c22 JOIN tb__armario USING(idclient,messurement_date)  
  ) kw2 USING(idclient) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT idclient,A_KW a_kw3,B_KW b_kw3,total_KW total_kw3 FROM (
        SELECT idclient,MAX(messurement_date) messurement_date
          FROM (
            SELECT * FROM tb__armario LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT idclient,MAX(messurement_date) messurement_date
                FROM tb__armario GROUP BY 1
                UNION
              SELECT idclient,MAX(messurement_date) messurement_date
                FROM (
                  SELECT * FROM tb__armario LEFT JOIN (
                      SELECT idclient,MAX(messurement_date) messurement_date
                        FROM tb__armario GROUP BY 1 
                    ) c1 USING(idclient,messurement_date)
                    WHERE c1.idclient IS NULL  
                ) tb__armario GROUP BY 1
              ) c1 USING(idclient,messurement_date)
              WHERE c1.idclient IS NULL  
          ) tb__armario GROUP BY 1
      ) c33 JOIN tb__armario USING(idclient,messurement_date)  
  ) kw3 USING(idclient);

CREATE TABLE tb__armario (
  id_armario INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idclient INT,
  cabinet_id INT,
  messurement_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  A_KW INT,
  B_KW INT,
  total_KW INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_armario)
);

INSERT INTO tb__armario VALUES
(1, 5, 573, '2017-05-10', 100, 200, 300),
(2, 77, 9984, '2017-05-06', 500, 1000, 1500),
(3, 92, 232, '2017-02-11', 500, 400, 900),
(4, 123, 9977, '2017-01-29', 350, 500, 850),
(5, 5, 573, '2017-04-10', 500, 200, 700),
(6, 77, 9984, '2017-05-01', 333, 333, 999),
(7, 92, 232, '2017-01-10', 547, 553, 1100),
(8, 123, 9977, '2017-01-26', 200, 350, 550),
(9, 5, 573, '2017-04-06', 500, 200, 700),
(10, 77, 9984, '2017-03-03', 333, 333, 999),
(11, 92, 232, '2017-01-04', 547, 553, 1100);
```

Comment: David, si pudieras dar una breve explicacion seria bueno. Te recomiendo revisar el articulo [mcve].